# how to open jupyter projects on anyother IDE like vs_code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ide

I am working with Juypter Notebook for a long time and I want to open my projects in vs_code (or any other IDE) and my "juypter_projects" folder where I contain all my Jupyter notebook projects appears in this way:  (please try to understand my handwriting ) [image: Inside my juypter_projects folder]

and inside the .ipynb_checkpoints folder which is located inside the juypter_projects folder seems in this way:

[image: .ipynb_checkpoints folder looks like this]

**and looks like none of the files inside these folders are of .py extension**

hence so I dont know which file should I choose to open when trying to edit my code in other IDEs
and so when I tried to open them in any IDE like vs_code it is not working and this limits me to only edit my code inside "Juypter Notebook" and please tell me how can I open Juptyer Notebook projects and edit them in other IDEs... Thank You

Comment: notebook files are of extension `*.ipynb`

Comment: It seems that you save .ipynb as PDF file, what @JustinMai says is right, and you can also export .ipynb as .py file, please refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_export-your-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 1):

When you write code in Jupyter cells, the notebook (.ipynb) is converted into a JSON object, making it very difficult to work in an IDE.

The solution my company landed on is writing everything in external python modules and importing them into the notebook.  We use Jupyter widgets extensively and they can be imported into .py files as easily as importing them into notebooks.  In the end, we get a library of custom widgets and modules that can be used by everyone, and since it's just python, we can build/edit in any IDE.  I use Sublime.

There may be other ways, but this approach works so well for us that we've stopped looking for alternatives.